# MySQL on Windows or Linux

Tags: mysql, linux, windows, amazon-ec2

I am new to the Database region while have to migrate the company's database from AWS RDS to AWS EC2 and subscribe MySQL Enterprise edition.

What I am confused now is which OS should I choose, Windows or Linux? The most important thing is the performance, which one would MySQL perform better? If its Linux, is it possible to use Ubuntu OS? Can anyone help to advise?

Really appreciate!

Comment: It is a heavily opinion-based question. Mysql typically performs better on Linux and you have a better control over what is going exactly in your system. The disadvantage is that you have to learn, how to control it. But fortunately you have StackExchange and StackOverflow for that. :-) You have also no licensing problems. But it is my opinion, and you know, *"opinions are like ..., everybody has one but no one is curious to the others'"*. :-)

Comment: Choose what you have experience with or use most (or want to use) elsewhere in the company. Ubuntu is a reasonable OS to choose, but again, choose what you have experience with.

Comment: Thanks guys. Really appreciated! Actually I really want to use Ubuntu as I feel like this would be more common and more control as well. Although as you said, I am not that confident especially when everyone else in the company is more familiar with Windows base.

Comment: Implement first.  Six months down the road, rethink the schema, OS, MySQL/MariaDB, etc.  By then you will understand the requirements better.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the person who is managing the server. you can make decision based on following points:

- If you are familiar with commands based administrative tasks, then Ubuntu Server edition is a better choice, as finding and installing required tools is easier compared to other distros. Best part is reduced overhead of Licencing and GUI.
- If you prefer GUI based administration, then windows is good choice.

Comment: I think getting familiar with commands based administrative tasks would be more helpful in the following career development and as for the GUI, I think I could still use the MySQL Workbench to connect via my local machine. Thanks

Comment: Choosing linux for mysql is good idea. Yes you can use workbench from your local machine, but make sure that root user must be protected enough and can be used from allowed IPs only.

Answer (score 1):

For tools such as MySQL is a better desition working with Linux operating systems, better compatibility, more tools to increase productivity, obviously costs licenses are important

There are facts like these to make a desition

1. For open source technologies such as PHP, MySQL o MariaDB is a better way to choose Linux distros
2. For closed technologies such as C#, SQL Server .NET a better way is Microsoft for performance and to gain compatibility

For example for tunning mysql server most of the tools are available for Linux distros

In the case for exa,mple of mariaDB for building a good dataware house, the most common tools are available for linux distros

For example in mariaDB if you want to use mariaDB Max Scale that is a columnar storage engine; the only supported opearting systems are

1. RedHat CentOS
2. Ubuntu
3. Debian
4. SLES

> I mean how you can see if you choose windows over Linux you will be
>   limited about using features of the Dtabase Engine

Comment: Thanks for sharing you hands-on experience. I feel like it is of more control to use linux as well.

Comment: yeah because mysql/mariadb are oriented those platforms @Jupyterous